# How to access pasted rows in PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I want to access the rows of a PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet, after I have pasted data from an excel sheet into it.
Ideally, I want to iterate through the rows of the sheet that contain data (as the values in the row should make up one object).

I have tried using this statement 
`List<SheetUpdate> updates = sheet.getUpdates();` intending to iterate through it to access the row data with 
`update.getNewValue();` , but `updates` is always empty even if ajax detects the change (paste action).

Could you suggest a way to access a specific row of a PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet?

Comment: Is your issue similar to this reported issue? https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/588

Comment: @Melloware not quite actually, since `updates` is always empty no matter where I paste the data. No new rows are created when this problem occurs. 
Is `getUpdates()` the only approach to access the rows?

Comment: Hmmm i am not sure I have never had this use case in any of my production code.  If you debug it let me know if there is anything I can fix in the component.